# iOS 8 Upgrade - Full Screen Mode: Onscreen keyboard flashes briefly on first tap of text field, appears properly on second tap

Tags: html, angularjs, ipad, ios8, on-screen-keyboard

I have a weird problem on my web app(AngularJS HTML5). Upon upgrading my iPad to iOS8, the onscreen keyboard is behaving weirdly. Upon tapping a text field once, the keyboard (very) briefly flashes and goes away. It is almost impossible to see - there's only a dark flash at the bottom of the screen. Upon tapping again, the keyboard comes up fine. has anybody else faced this issue? It is driving me crazy!

This is the input field:

HTML:

```
<input valid-number ng-disabled="planBody.isSubmitted==='Y'" type="tel" maxlength="13" ng-model="planBody.campaign.campaignparams.budget" ng-required="true" currency-input=""/>
```

JS:

```
    .directive('validNumber', function() {
      return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
          if(!ngModelCtrl) {
            return; 
          }

          ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(val) {
            if(angular.isUndefinedOrNull(val))
            {
              val = "";
            }
            var clean = val.replace( /[^0-9]+/g, '');
            if (val !== clean) {
              ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(clean);
              ngModelCtrl.$render();
            }
            return clean;
          });

          element.bind('keypress', function(event) {
            if(event.keyCode === 32) {
              event.preventDefault();
            }
          });
        }
      };
    })
    .directive('currencyInput', function($filter, $browser) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            var listener = function() {
                var value = $element.val().replace(/,/g, '');
                if(value !== ""){
                   $element.val($filter('number')(value, false));
                }
                $scope.markForSaveAlert();
            };

            // This runs when we update the text field
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(viewValue) {
                return viewValue.replace(/,/g, '');
            });

            // This runs when the model gets updated on the scope directly and keeps our view in sync
              ngModelCtrl.$render = function() {
              if(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue!==''){
                 $element.val($filter('number')(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue, false));
                }
             };

            $element.bind('change', listener);
            $element.bind('keydown', function(event) {
                var key = event.keyCode;
                // If the keys include the CTRL, SHIFT, ALT, or META keys, or the arrow keys, do nothing.
                // This lets us support copy and paste too
                if (key == 91 || (15 < key && key < 19) || (37 <= key && key <= 40)){
                  return;
                }
                $browser.defer(listener); // Have to do this or changes don't get picked up properly
            });

            $element.bind('paste cut', function() {
                $browser.defer(listener);  
            });
        }

    };
})
```

Update: THis seems to happen only on full screen mode, not in regular mobile Safari

Comment: It might be possible issue of iOS8, iOS 8.0.x was having many issues like this try upgrading to iOS 8.1, and hope that resolved your issue.

Comment: I'm running on 8.1. Still having the issue. Is there a link to the common issues that were occurring on 8.0.x?@Yuvrajsinh

Comment: Are you doing any operation on text field?

Comment: I've added the code above. Just a couple of AngularJS Directives

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this one. I used the Safari console debugger to see what events were getting fired. Looks like ng-touch (Angular Touch) was causing the issue, firing multiple events along with the regular click event that was getting fired. I removed Angular Touch (which wasn't being used anyway) and the functionality started working fine.